# Check if enum type exists and add value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I'm new to PostgreSQl. I'm trying to add new values to type if type exists:

```sql
ALTER type ProcessStatus ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 'Processing';
```

Above query will add 'Processing' to type ProcessStatus, but I want to check if type exists first.

I tried like below

```sql
DO $$                                               
BEGIN                                                        
  IF EXISTS(SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'ProcessStatus')
  THEN                                                        
      ALTER TYPE ProcessStatus ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 'Processing';
  END IF;                                                        
END $$;
```

I get this error when type doesn't exist:

> SQL Error [25001]: ERROR: ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot be executed from a
> function